# how to iterate through folders and make changes in the files in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder structure in the following way:

[image]

I need to go to the folder where csv files are present and add header to them and then go to the next folder , add header and so on. How to iterate through the multiple folders and do the changes to the csv file using python? Can anyone please tell me how to do it in python?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is what you need I guess

Comment: use python glob package. glob.glob("*.csv", recursive=True) will work for you

Comment: See [examples of glob here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/). It saves you the job of building your own recursive function.